# Repository Tool for IT Landscape Artifacts Software Services

Tags: repository, content-management-system, documentation, togaf, enterprise-architecture

We are looking to store our Software company's all documents which can be easily modified, searched, shared withing Teams.

It is like Sharepoint but need more sophisticated tool which undertand various document formats

Like Swagger , Code Files, Excel, and very well sturcutre to orgainize and link documents.

We can to create our Architecture and Solution Repository

Comment: I have used Sparx EA for storing all architecture related artefacts along with version control. Once they are captured in EA, we then run (scheduled) code that will export the contents as HTML to our internal SharePoint site which then can be used by all to search across. Of course, you will need to structure EA as per your dialects. The github repo (https://github.com/gundumon/ArchitectureGuild) contains code to export EA contents to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

ok, then you need:
1- a store

2- version control utility

3- a tool too develop togaf specific stuff (views, viewpoints, stackholder definitions, ABBs, SBBs, architecture diagrams, container documents that refers to these diagrams such as architecture definition and architecture contract docs )

4- a tool to understand various document formats to track the changes internally (including word documents and excel sheets)

let me start from bottom up,

4-I don't know any tool that is able to understand complex format like docx, even microsoft tfs deals with word files as a binary file, thus it can't track the changes done inside a document, I think you will need to compromise this point and rely more on a well structured process of providing sufficient and precise comments by whoever commits to the repository + well utilizing components in point 3

3- Archi (free) - Sparx / visual paradigm (commercial) (I have a very small experience with it but it seems to be sufficient)

2- any source control tool (git / svn / tfs / mercural) .. and if you use Archi, it's eclipse based and eclipse has plugins to most of source control tools

1- according to point 2, the repository will be defined, in case of git for example it will be a Git repository

but any ways, you will need to define a process and guidelines inside your organization for managing the architectures then the tools will just support.

Though not perfect, hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit late, let me try to answer from my experience. Enterprise Architecture Platforms / Tool should fit your expectations with many more features that you need for architecting solutions other than the primary document management, collaborations and content management.

I suggest you to look at [Orbus IServer](https://www.orbussoftware.com/iServer) as it is purely document based. It accepts all Microsoft format files like visio, excel, docx, powerpoint, sharepoint, power bi. It also accepts ERWIN files

Here is the [link](https://www.orbussoftware.com/solutions/capabilities#Integration) which speaks about its integration.